# How do submit an object to a struts2 action using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, struts2

I have an object that I'm populating from a selection off a table row that a user selects.  I have a jQuery function that captures the click event and a hidden form field populates an id I need.

However, I'm not sure as to the proper way to send off that object to a struts2 action?  I tried using this:

```
$(function() {
    $('#tbl tr').click(function() {
            var id = $(this).closest('tr').find('input:hidden').val();
 var page = "<s:url action='update/deleteInfo.action'/>?model.isDelete=true&model.info.id=id"; 
          console.log(page);
    window.location.href=(page);
   });
});
```

The model object has an isDelete boolean variable and the model has a nested info object that has an id variable with getter/setters.

However, when I send this across, the model object isn't populated with these entries.  Is there a way to do this or a better way than the url tag?

Comment: You might need to include more details, but you should also include how the HTML is rendering as a sanity check of the `page` variable's value. [The boolean value, however, should be set via `setDelete`--`isDelete` is for the getter.](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch06_02.htm#INDEX-963)

Comment: I can't duplicate the behavior; what version of S2 are you using? I suspect it's your `<s:url>` tag, unless you've explicitly configured S2 to allow slashes in action names. You also shouldn't need to include the action extension manually.

Comment: It's version 2.3x I think. I'll have to check.

Comment: That's what I tested under, check your url. Try the submission manually from the browser.

Comment: Will do.  I can check it from work tomorrow.  Thx, Dave.

Comment: @JamesDrinkard i have similar doubt please reply http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13923995/how-to-pass-parameter-value-from-a-jquery-function-to-struts2-url-tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of your url, `id` should be appended as a variable not string

```
var page = "<s:url action='update/deleteInfo.action'/>?model.isDelete=true&model.info.id="+id;
```